# Player move other objects Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

What I want to achieve is Player move other objects in 2D.

I followed the UFO tutorial from Unity webpage and all objects are collectable not movable. What should I change to UFO tutorial in order to be able to push the objects by player?

Comment: Do you have Rigidbody attached to any of your objects?

Comment: Thanks that was the issue